# I cant redirect url with rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, url-rewriting

```
http://localhost/shorter/?aQ3d4B
(http://localhost/shorter/index.php?aQ3d4B)
```

I want redirect url without question mark.

so ;

```
http://localhost/shorter/aQ3d4B
```

This is not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule shorter/(.*)/ ?$1
RewriteRule shorter/(.*) ?$1
```

What i must write to .htaccess file.

Comment: Can you write the code for me ?

Comment: Please enter a little bit of .htaccess knowledge. You learn a lot more if you look for yourself.
Have you read the url in the comment above? It also provides you a solution.

Comment: i trying every way but i canttttt !

Comment: This is not a free coding service Yavuz. You're expected to do the leg work yourself. If you want someone to write all your code, there are plenty of Freelancers who you can pay for such things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^shorter/(\w+)*$ ./shorter?id=$1
```

This will give you a `$_GET['id']` in your PHP

Comment: i dont use  id. i did try your code but page says ; The object does not exist!

The URL in the request is not found on the server. If you have manually entered the URL, observe what you wrote and try again.

Comment: actually, chenge that \d+ to \w+, that wants digits only!

Comment: could not with w+

Comment: can you come teamwier ?